# What is the best way to secure localstorage Data in my clientapp

Tags: reactjs, security, encryption, browser, local-storage

I have a react app, where i store all my customerprofile details like username, emailid, roles etc.. Anyone can goto debugger tool view that data, thought of encrypting & decrypting of localstorage but not sure is it good approach? what is the best way to do secure it?

Comment: You'd have to encrypt and decrypt on the server side to actually help, otherwise they could just do it themselves with a little extra effort to look through your JS which can also be found in the debugger. But I question whether it actually needs to be protected. Presumably the person finding these details in the debugger has already provided credentials to be allowed to use that data in the first place..

Comment: Thankyou Brian. Yes i need to secure it because my token is valid for 24hours & which will be stored in localstorage, so wanted to secure customer data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Manjunath! You better store it on backend and get the token from server to frontend and store it in http only cookie, but anyways if your requirement is to store it on frontend, then I'd crypt it with cryptojs or bcyptjs and then store it on frontend, but better in a cookie, so for further integration with backend (if any), you'll be able to send cookie data automatically (for eg, to verify user, etc.). It will be in your req.cookies.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs

Comment: Question if I store something that is not related to the user but more for keeping some data persistent when refreshing the page. Is it still unsafe? Also, these data are just displayed as text buttons.

Comment: @CodeTech the issue with local storage is that someone can easily access that data. Whether it's "unsafe" depends on the outcome of someone accessing that data. If you store sensitive data, then it's unsafe. Otherwise it's what local storage is for.

Answer (score 3):

we can use **react-secure-storage** to store and retrieve securely data in localstorage in the fllowing way

```
secureLocalStorage.setItem("boolean", true); // to store data 
secureLocalStorage.getItem("boolean"); // to retrieve data
```

**Example:**

```
import { useEffect } from  "react";
import  secureLocalStorage  from  "react-secure-storage";

  
const App = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        secureLocalStorage.setItem("object", {
            message:  "This is testing of local storage",
        });
        secureLocalStorage.setItem("number", 12);
        secureLocalStorage.setItem("string", "12");
        secureLocalStorage.setItem("boolean", true); // to store data 
        let value = secureLocalStorage.getItem("boolean"); // to retrieve data
    }, []);

   return (
        <div>
            This is a sample code
        </div>
    );
}

export  default  App;
```

Comment: Really happy to see my library has been recommended by others...

Comment: @SushinPv while researching on securing my localstorage data i came across your library.
Is it really secure than the native localstorage.
How does it work agains cross attacks?
Could you please enlighten us?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to secure your local storage data, use the `npm module crypto-js.`

Step 1.

```
npm install crypto-js --save
```

Step 2. Create a file and call it util.js and paste the following code.

```
import CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
                                    
 export const encryptData = (data, salt) =>
 CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(data), salt).toString();
                                    
                                    
export const decryptData = (ciphertext, salt) => {
const bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(ciphertext, salt);
try {
 return JSON.parse(bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
}catch(err){
 return null;
 }
}
```

Step 3. Encrypt the data using encryptData():

```
import {encryptData} from './utils';
                    
const originalData={
    name:'IDKBlogs'
}
const salt = process.env.SALT || '6d090796-ecdf-11ea-adc1-0242ac112345';
const encryptedData = encryptData(originalData, salt);
localStorage.setItem('SOME_NON_RADABLE_KEY', encryptedData); // SOME_NON_RADABLE_KEY like 'mk' as 'myKey'
```

Step 4. Decrypt the data using decryptData():

```
import { decryptData } from './utils';

let mkLocalData = localStorage.getItem('mk');
  if(!mkLocalData){
       // Handle, if there is no data in localStorage, or if someone deleted the localStorage.
    }
const salt = process.env.SALT || '6d090796-ecdf-11ea-adc1-0242ac112345';
const originalData = decryptData(mkLocalData, salt);
if(!originalData){
  // will executes if someone altered the code in localstorage.
}
```

You can learn more about this here https://idkblogs.com/js/304/Secure-your-app-data-in-localStorage